# Assign and Query Javascript Arrow Function for Metadata

Tags: javascript, typescript

The problem is rather simple. We need to imbue a function with a parameter, and then simply extract that parameter from the body of the function. I'll present the outline in typescript...

```
abstract class Puzzle {

    abstract assign(param, fn): any;

    abstract getAssignedValue(): any;

    async test() {

        const wrapped = this.assign(222, async () => {
            return 555 + this.getAssignedValue();
        });

        console.log("Expecting", await wrapped(), "to be", 777);
    }
}
```

Let's set the scene:

- Assume strict mode, no arguments or callee. Should work reasonably well on the recent-ish version of v8.
- The function passed to `assign()` must be an anonymous arrow function that doesn't take any parameters.
- ... and it's also`async`. The assigned value could just be stored somewhere for the duration of the invocation, but because the function is `async` and can have `await`s, you can't rely on the value keeping through multiple interleaved invocations.
- `this.getAssignedValue()` takes no parameters, returning whatever we assigned with the `assign()` method.

Would be great to find a more elegant solution that those I've presented below.

### Edit

Okay, we seem to have found a good solid solution inspired by zone.js. The same type of problem is solved there, and the solution is to override the meaning of some system-level primitives, such as SetTimeout and Promise. The only headache above was the async statement, which meant that the body of the function could be effectively reordered. Asyncs are ultimately triggered by promises, so you'll have to override your Promise with something that is context aware. It's quite involved, and because my use case is outside of browser or even node, I won't bore you with details. For most people hitting this kind of problem - just use zone.js.

Comment: It may be a "puzzle", but it's about a pure programming problem without silly restrictions, so I don't see any reason to say that it's off-topic here.

Comment: @Liam It's a puzzle in the sense that it's puzzling. This is an actual problem, as I'm sure you can tell from context.

Comment: There are hacky solutions, but it's still an X/Y problem. If this is an *actual issue* you're finding you need to solve, I'd expend effort into changing the essentially-broken requirements rather than to come up with ugly solutions

Comment: @certainperformance - I am not aware of any non-hacky solutions, that’s why I am asking here. It would be trivial to do with a function(), but in an arrow function you can’t rebind this. If no clean solution exists, obviously we’d have to do something different. It’s just not yet apparent what. Also, maybe near solutions exist? We discovered 2 so far, maybe there are more. 

Answer (score 0):

### Hacky Solution 2

```
class HackySolution2 extends Puzzle {

    assign(param: any, fn: AnyFunction): AnyFunction {
        const sub = Object(this);
        sub["getAssignedValue"] = () => param;
        return function () { return eval(fn.toString()); }.call(sub);
    }

    getAssignedValue() {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

In this solution, I'm making an object that overrides the `getAssignedValue()` method, and re-evaluates the source code of the passed function, effectively changing the meaning of `this`. Still not quite production grade...

#### Edit.

Oops, this breaks closures.

Answer (score 0):

### Hacky Solution 1

We actually have a working implementation. It's such a painful hack, but proves that this should be possible. Somehow. Maybe there's even a super simple solution that I'm missing just because I've been staring at this for too long.

```
class HackySolution extends Puzzle {

    private readonly repo = {};

    assign(param: any, fn) {

        // code is a random field for repo. It must also be a valid JS fn name.
        const code = 'd' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000001);
        // Store the parameter with this code.    
        this.repo[code] = param;

        // Create a function that has code as part of the name.
        const name = `FN_TOKEN_${code}_END_TOKEN`;
        const wrapper = new Function(`return function ${name}(){ return this(); }`)();

        // Proceed with normal invocation, sending fn as the this argument.
        return () => wrapper.call(fn);
    }

    getAssignedValue() {
        // Comb through the stack trace for our FN_TOKEN / END_TOKEN pair, and extract the code.
        const regex = /FN_TOKEN_(.*)_END_TOKEN/gm;
        const code = regexGetFirstGroup(regex, new Error().stack);
        return this.repo[code];
    }
}
```

So the idea in our solution is to examine the stack trace of the `new Error().stack`, and wrap something we can extract as a token, which in turn we'll put into a repo. Hacky? Very hacky.

#### Notes

Testing shows that this is actually quite workable, but requires a more modern execution environment than we have - i.e. ES2017+.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know typescript so possibly this isn't useful, but what about something like:

```js
const build_assign_hooks = () => {
  let assignment;
  
  const get_value = () => assignment;
  const assign = (param, fn) => {
    assignment = param;
    
    return fn;
  }
  
  return [assign, get_value];
};

class Puzzle {
  constructor() {
    const [assign, getAssignedValue] = build_assign_hooks();
    
    this.assign = assign;
    this.getAssignedValue = getAssignedValue;
  }

  async test() {
    const wrapped = this.assign(222, async () => {
        return 555 + this.getAssignedValue();
    });

    console.log("Expecting", await wrapped(), "to be", 777);
  }
}

const puzzle = new Puzzle();
puzzle.test();
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for multiple function definitions. The biggest problem is when async can reorder execution, and screw up any such direct assignments, so this doesn’t really work as a class of solutions.

Comment: Ah, thanks. It's clear I didn't really understand the question. I also tried setting a new object to `this` during the assign call (so that the this.getAssignedValue() pointed to a now old this), but (probably for very good reasons) it wouldn't let me do that.